# generate random values for unit testing Hast table data type

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, hashtable, random

My project generates few values(equal partitioning method) for each data types by getting the Minimum and Maximum values. I am doing this generating values for  functional testing, I am actually passing this values to nunit partner, max amd min are applicable to int, float, double etc., these values are test data .

Initially I generated for basic data types like int, float, double, string etc.

Now I need to support data types like DataSet, HashTable and other Collections.

```
public DataSet MySampleMethod(int param1, string param2, Hashtable ht)
```

For testing this function I can pass values for int and string but how will I pass test data for ht or how is test data generated for hash table?

Comment: What would be the minimum & maximum values for Collection Types. Pls clarify the behaviour you want to unit test clearly.

Comment: public DataSet MySampleMethod(int param1, string param2, Hashtable ht)
for testing this fuctions i can pass values for int and string but how will i pass test data for this fuction . or how is test data generated for hash table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First - I always seed my random values for unit tests, so that hey are repeatable - however, something like (using `Dictionary<,>` instead of `HashTable`, but equivalent):

```
        Random rand = new Random(123456); // note seed
        Dictionary<int, double> lookup = new Dictionary<int, double>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
        {
            lookup[rand.Next(100000)] = rand.NextDouble();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use random data at all for unit testing. A test may pass or fail randomly depending on the data chosen, and when you try to find out why it failed you may have a very hard time debugging the code because you can't repeat the failure in a predictable way.

Comment: As long as you seed the randomizer, there is nothing unpredictable about most RNG, and thus can be a reasonable approach for getting uniform (in the probability  sense) coverage without having to test each number in the Int32 range, for example. I use this in serialization tests, for example.

Comment: If you seed the random generator then you don't get random values. :)

Comment: my questing is what kind of data you need to generate in order to test a function which has hash table has data type

Comment: @Guffa - no, but you can generate a wide spread of uniformly distributed values, to provide a smoke-test without having to test every possible value.